# Gson not recognizing nested JSON object

Tags: java, gson

I try making the following POST request to my servlet:

```
$.post('SubmitDashboardInfo/reimbursementRequest',
          {
                startDate       : $('#startDate').val().trim(),
                endDate         : $('#endDate').val().trim(),
                expenseType     : $('#expenseType').val().trim(),
                eventDescription: $('#eventDescription').val().trim(),
                eventCost       : $('#eventCost').val().trim(),
                location        : {
                    streetAddress     : $('#streetAddress').val().trim(),
                    city              : $('#city').val().trim(),
                    stateAbbreviation : $('#state').val().trim(),
                    zipCode           : $('#zipCode').val().trim()
                }/*,
                gradeScale      : $.makeArray($('#gradeScales > tr').map(function() { 
                    var tds = $(this).children('td');
                    return { 
                        letterGrade : $($(tds)[0]).text(),
                        lowerLimit  : $($(tds)[1]).text()
                    };
                }))*/
            }, 
            function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            })
```

, which calls the following service method:

```
public static boolean validateUserForm(HttpServletRequest req)
{

    // get all the parameters here
    try {
        Type type = new TypeToken<ReimbursementRequest>() {}.getType();
        ReimbursementRequest rr = gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), type);
        System.out.println(rr.toString());


    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (JsonIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My `ReimbursementRequest` POJO looks like this:

```
package p1.revature.beans;

public class ReimbursementRequest extends Bean {
private int id, requesterID;
private double amount;
private String status;
private int reimbursableEventID;
private ReimbursableEvent reimbursableEvent;


/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public ReimbursementRequest() {
    super();
}
/**
 * Constructor for everything but the id. This is used to insert into the reimbursement request table
 * @param requesterID : the ID of the Employee requesting reimbursement
 * @param amount : the amount requested
 * @param status : the status of the request
 * @param reimbursableEventID : the id of the ReimbursableEvent the requester is trying to have covered
 */
public ReimbursementRequest(int requesterID, double amount, String status, int reimbursableEventID) {
    super();
    this.requesterID = requesterID;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.status = status;
    this.reimbursableEventID = reimbursableEventID;
}

/**
 * Constructor for every field but the reimbursable event id. Used for rendering material client-side
 * @param id
 * @param requesterID
 * @param amount
 * @param status
 * @param reimbursableEvent
 */
public ReimbursementRequest(int id, int requesterID, double amount, String status,
        ReimbursableEvent reimbursableEvent) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.requesterID = requesterID;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.status = status;
    this.reimbursableEvent = reimbursableEvent;
}
/**
 * Constructor for every field. Used for select queries.
 * @param id : the primary key of this request
 * @param requesterID : the ID of the Employee requesting reimbursement
 * @param amount : the amount requested
 * @param status : the status of the request
 * @param reimbursableEventID : the id of the ReimbursableEvent the requester is trying to have covered
 */
public ReimbursementRequest(int id, int requesterID, double amount, String status, int reimbursableEventID) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.requesterID = requesterID;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.status = status;
    this.reimbursableEventID = reimbursableEventID;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getRequesterID() {
    return requesterID;
}
public void setRequesterID(int requesterID) {
    this.requesterID = requesterID;
}
public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public int getReimbursableEventID() {
    return reimbursableEventID;
}
public void setReimbursableEventID(int reimbursableEventID) {
    this.reimbursableEventID = reimbursableEventID;
}
public ReimbursableEvent getReimbursableEvent() {
    return reimbursableEvent;
}
public void setReimbursableEvent(ReimbursableEvent reimbursableEvent) {
    this.reimbursableEvent = reimbursableEvent;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ReimbursementRequest [id=" + id + ", requesterID=" + requesterID + ", amount=" + amount + ", status="
            + status + ", reimbursableEventID=" + reimbursableEventID + ", reimbursableEvent=" + reimbursableEvent
            + "]";
}


}
```

For some reason, Gson thinks I'm passing it a plain ol string, when I'm actually passing it a JSON string. It returns this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
    at p1.revature.services.HandleDashboardData.validateUserForm(HandleDashboardData.java:34)
    at p1.revature.servlets.SubmitDashboardInfo.doPost(SubmitDashboardInfo.java:32)
```

I'm desperately trying to get this project, which is due in 2 days, done. I know this is literally a lot, but please help with this...

Comment: please provide `req.getReader()` in debug mode.

Comment: Can you debug what `req.getReader()` prints out and attach it to the question?

Comment: And the POJO does not look at all like the JSON you are passing to create it. did you add the corrrect code?

Comment: I noticed that as well. I'm up now taking care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data as a json object...
Stringify.json

I shall try finding an example for you.

Cheers
Vicky

Comment: You mean `JSON.stringify()`? That makes the object a `string`.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(pass your data)

Comment: Mike.. can you please cross check the function posting data... Shouldn't you have a "data" variable defined which shall be passed?

Comment: function postSelectedDataToServer() {

 //var finalJson = '{"patientId":2, "medDataList":';
 var patientJsonInfo = $("#userDetails").text();
 
 var finalJson = '{"patientInfo":'+patientJsonInfo+',"medDataList":';
 var jsonFormData = JSON.stringify(selectTableData);
 
 $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : '/postSelectedData',
  dataType : 'json',
  contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data : finalJson+jsonFormData+'}',
  success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   var jsonObj = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
   
   var myObj = decodeURIComponent(jsonObj);
   
   var j

Comment: Hi Mike, if json.stringify resolved your issue.. could I ask you to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After talking over this with a friend, I found that I should be serializing the JavaScript objects with `JSON.stringify(myBusinessObj);` to send them to the server.

The questions he was asking to me as of why, stumped the hell out of me...